# How to set permission for users of a network shared folder so that they cannot delete files added by other users

Tags: windows-7, networking, permissions

In Windows 7, how can I set permissions to a network shared folder so that users can add or delete their own added files but cannot delete files added by other users to that folder?

Answer (score 1):

there, it seems to be impossible to set different privileges for different users on the same file folder. To make sure someone won't delete or edit files added by others, the workable way is to put them into different folder and set full control/modify/read permission respectively. Here is a [guide](http://blog.doohelp.com/how-to-set-permissions-on-shared-file-folders-in-windows-7/) I found.

Comment: so.. what you are suggesting is that I set different permissions to different users based on their respective IP addresses ?